# python beautifulsoup shorten code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

is there a more effecient way to write this to only take up one line? This works but I feel this can somehow be compressed down to a single line of code

python

```
del(thearticle['data-book-api'])
del(thearticle['data-book-human'])
del(thearticle['data-book'])
del(thearticle['data-chapter'])
del(thearticle['data-selected-verses'])
del(thearticle['data-verse-modal-enabled'])
del(thearticle['data-version'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a for:

```
for key in ['data-book-api', 'data-book-human', ...]:
    del thearticle[key]
```

Btw. `del` is not a function.